# Flow accumulation on grid in R

Tags: r, elevation, grids-graticules, flow

I would like to calculate the number of cells from gridded elevation data that drain into a particular cell. First,  I calculate the flow direction by selecting the cell with the steepest slope from one out of eight adjacent cells.

```
library(raster)
library(gdistance) # package for adjacent function

# make the blank raster, the extents and resolution of which are up to you.
# the cells are numbered 1 to ncell (starting in the top left in R)
r <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=6,ymn=0,ymx=6,res=c(2,2))
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

# flow direction of digital elevation model
flow <- terrain(subelevation, opt="flowdir", neighbors=8)
# transform to matrix 
dim(flow@data@values) <- c(sqrt(length(flow@data@values)), sqrt(length(flow@data@values))) 
# yields values from 1 to 128, see Figure 1
flow@data@values
```

**Figure 1**

[image]

Figure 2 plots `flow@data@values` transformed to an `igraph` object to illustrate the problem. For any chosen cell, I would like to calculate the number of incoming cells connected at any distance. For example if the cell labelled *A* is chosen, it should have the value 3 as *B*, *C* and *D* drain into it. The more efficient the solution, the better as the gridded dataset is large.

**Figure 2**

[image]

Comment: Why not do this in a GIS that has more robust algorithms than D8? If you would like to stay in R you can use the package interfaces to GRASS (`rgrass7`), SAGA (`RSAGA`), or indirectly QGIS (`RQGIS`). Computationally, this will be much more efficient as well as providing flow direction algorithms such as, D-infinity.

Comment: I have been mostly using ```R``` which is why I would prefer this program. There must be a neat way of doing this. ```igraph``` allows finding clusters of nodes. Maybe, I can achieve this by identifying clusters of nodes.

Answer (score 5):

##### Short answer:

`whitebox::wbt_d8_flow_accumulation()` calculates a flow accumulation grid.

##### Long answer:

I was trying to find a method for doing this in R, for stream network and hydrology analysis. It was surprisingly hard to find an answer, with most suggestions involving bridging to another GIS software which I wasn't overly excited about, but I have found a very simple way!

It uses the R package `whitebox`, which admittedly is an R-frontend for *Whitebox Tools* software; see [here](https://rdrr.io/github/giswqs/whiteboxR/f/README.md) for details on the package, and [here](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/intro.html) for info on *Whitebox Tools* software and detailed functionalities. Don't be put off by the fact it isn't 100% R (I didn't even realise this until I started looking at other functions), because there is an almost endless list of awesome functions inside it.

I discovered this package through [JP Gannon's "Hydroinfomatics at VT" bookdown](https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/), which has some great examples of stream network analysis. Here, I have basically copied from those examples (for the sake of providing an example rather than just the link), but modified to include different data. Specifically, I am taking the workflow from Chapters 15 and 16 - do read these as it explains the process in better detail than the following minimal example.

First up, load the packages we will be using:

```
library(terra)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)

#install.packages("whitebox", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(whitebox)
```

For this example we use the `srtm` elevation raster of Zion National Park, from the `spDataLarge` package. We attach it and then save it locally in `my_folder` (this is important), and then import and plot it.

```
# load elevation data from spDataLarge package (elevation data for Zion National Park)
# save sample data locally
system.file("raster/srtm.tif", package = "spDataLarge") %>% 
  rast %>% 
  writeRaster('my_folder/my_rast.tif', overwrite = TRUE)

# import dem
rast('my_folder/my_rast.tif') %>% 
  {. ->> my_rast}

tmap_mode('view')

tm_shape(my_rast)+
  tm_raster(style = 'cont', palette = 'viridis')
```

[image]

Now we crack into `whitebox`. Without repeating [the original example](https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/), basically `whitebox` functions look a little different to what you're probably used to - instead of R objects as inputs and outputs, you work with filepaths (this is why we saved our raster locally in our own folder). I assume this has something to do with `whitebox` package being a frontend for the standalone *Whitebox Tools* software.

The first thing we do is to prepare the raster for analysis. This involves 'filling in' single-cell holes/pits/depressions as this can cause drainage paths to terminate unexpectedly. Likewise, we 'breach' larger depressions (see [the original examples](https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/) for more details). You can see here we supply the functions with filepaths for (input) `dem` and `output` objects.

```
# fill and breach
wbt_fill_single_cell_pits(
  dem = 'my_folder/my_rast.tif', 
  output = 'my_folder/my_rast_filled.tif'
)

wbt_breach_depressions_least_cost(
  dem = 'my_folder/my_rast_filled.tif', 
  output = 'my_folder/my_rast_filled_breached.tif', 
  dist = 5
)
```

Next step we calculate a (D8) flow accumulation grid - cell values in the output represent the number of cells that flow into it. This can be changed to catchment area or specific catchment area - see [the original example](https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/).

This is essentially the answer to the original question, so once it is created we also import it into R.

```
# D8 flow accumulation
wbt_d8_flow_accumulation(
  input = 'my_folder/my_rast_filled_breached.tif', 
  output = 'my_folder/my_rast_d8fa.tif', 
  out_type = 'cells'
)

# now, we can import the flow accumulation raster
rast('my_folder/my_rast_d8fa.tif') %>% 
  {. ->> my_rast_d8fa}

my_rast_d8fa

# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 457, 465, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.0008333333  (x, y)
# extent      : -113.2396, -112.8521, 37.13208, 37.51292  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source      : my_rast_d8fa.tif 
# name        : my_rast_d8fa
```

And, we plot it:

```
tm_shape(my_rast_d8fa)+
  tm_raster(palette = 'viridis')
```

[image]

Due to massive variation in values (some cells have 10-100 cells draining into them, others at the bottom of the landscape have 100,000-200,000), this is hard to visualise. Rather, we plot log-transformed values:

```
tm_shape(my_rast_d8fa %>% log10)+
  tm_raster(palette = 'viridis')
```

[image]

Unsurprisingly, this looks like a stream network!

So, once you've got the raster in R, you can pull out the values for each cell whichever way suits:

```
my_rast_d8fa %>% 
  raster::as.data.frame(xy = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  rename(
    n_cells = my_rast_d8fa
  )
# # A tibble: 212,404 x 3
#        x     y n_cells
#    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1  -113.  37.5       1
# 2  -113.  37.5       3
# 3  -113.  37.5       4
# 4  -113.  37.5       5
# 5  -113.  37.5       6
# 6  -113.  37.5       1
# 7  -113.  37.5       1
# 8  -113.  37.5       1
# 9  -113.  37.5       1
# 10 -113.  37.5       2
# # ... with 212,394 more rows


my_rast_d8fa %>% 
  terra::values() %>% 
  head
#      my_rast_d8fa
# [1,]            1
# [2,]            3
# [3,]            4
# [4,]            5
# [5,]            6
# [6,]            1
```

Bonus - If you're doing stream analysis, you can also extract streams from the flow accumulation raster. You just need to provide a threshold for flow accumulation values to distinguish streams from non-streams:

```
# extract streams
wbt_extract_streams(
  flow_accum = 'my_folder/my_rast_d8fa.tif', 
  output = 'my_folder/raster_streams.tif', 
  threshold = 5000
)

# import and inspect streams raster
rast('my_folder/raster_streams.tif') %>% 
  {. ->> my_rast_streams}

# plot streams raster
tm_shape(my_rast)+
  tm_raster(style = 'cont', palette = 'viridis')+
  tm_shape(my_rast_streams)+
  tm_raster(palette = c('white'), legend.show = FALSE)
```

[image]

##### Notes:

For me, the `wbt_fill_*` and `wbt_breach_*` functions didn't cooperate when I had the `dem` in the working directory, but was fine when I put `dem` in a subfolder (`my_folder`).

D8 and D-Infinity flow accumulation grids can both be created - the example explains the difference but which one you want will depend on your exact situation I guess. D-Infinity looks like it would generally be a more 'realistic' representation of overland water flow, but I don't know enough about this type of analysis to say which one is more appropriate (from what I have read there is no right/wrong).

Comment: I have also had issues when there is whitespace in the file path or file name. Replacing whitespace with underscores has helped me a couple of times.